# Why isn't there an universal nuclear model?

Tags: nuclear-physics, strong-force

What problems does (low energy) nuclear physics face when trying to model the nuclear structure? Why isn't possible to have a theoretical model that can be used to describe any nucleus?

Comment: I'm no expert, but QCD is non-perturbative at low energies, and the nucleus contains many quarks, so it becomes very difficult to model the nucleus exactly theoretically.

Comment: We have models, I think you mean formula.

Comment: there exist a number of models . look at this http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Nuclear/shell.html , and this http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Nuclear/shell.html , and this https://journals.aps.org/rmp/abstract/10.1103/RevModPhys.54.913 . depending on the observables studied there are effective models of nuclear structure.